# Is there a fast way to extract elements in a list of data frames?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a fast way to extract elements in a list of data frames.

To do this, I've tested the function `lapply`. Here is a reproducible example:

```
  i <- 2
  dat <- replicate(100000, data.frame(x=1:5000, y = 1:5000, z = 1:5000), simplify=FALSE)
  system.time(test <- lapply(dat, function(y) y[i, c("x", "y")]))

   user  system elapsed 
   7.69    0.00    7.73
```

Ideally, the elapsed time should be <= 1 second.

Comment: if all your data is numeric you can use matrices instead

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also have columns that are not numeric. But the columns "x" and "y" are numeric.

Comment: Are you the one who built your input data ? A solution might be to adopt a more efficient design upstream.

Comment: Yes, I built the input data. The data frames have 13 columns and 5000 rows: 11 columns are numeric and 2 columns are not numeric. If it's more efficient to use matrices, I can convert the categorical columns to numeric ?

Comment: I suppose you could use matrices if either the levels were all the same or you saved the levels for each data.frame. If you don't save the levels before converting to matrix, then that information will be lost at the time of coercion.

Comment: looping on data frames to convert as matrix will be just as slow, but if from the start you store your numeric data (or just `x` and `y`) into a numeric 3D array your subset will just consist of getting a slice of this cube, which will be especially fast if you orient your cube the right way. Alternatively, just store x and y values in 2 matrices for a simpler abstraction.